# What's wrong with my IF statement and LWP::Simple?

Tags: perl, scrape

I am trying to create a simple scraper, and I am using getstore(), but the scirpt won't create the .txt file when used within an IF statement. What am I doing wrong there?

Thanks,

Carlos N.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url;
my $content;

print "Enter URL:";

chomp($url = <STDIN>);

$content = get($url);


if ($content =~ s%<(style|script)[^<>]*>.*?</\1>|</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>|<!--.*?-->%%g) {

    $content = getstore($content,"../crawled_text.txt");
}   


die "Couldn't get $url" unless defined $content;
```

Comment: I'd say the part where you are trying to parse HTML with regex is not the best idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the LWP::Simple documentation:

> my $code = getstore($url, $file)
>
> Gets a document identified by a URL and stores it in the file. The
> return value is the HTTP response code.

Your first parameter is a stripped HTML file and likely not a URL. You could use a debugger or print statements in your code to understand more about the contents of your variables and about whether your program goes into an if block.

Answer (score 0):

`getstore` takes an URL as a parameter and stores it into a file. What you want to do is to just store content in a file, so use this instead

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;
use Path::Tiny;

my $url = shift || "https://perl.org";
my $content = get($url) or die "Couldn't get $url" ;

if ($content =~ s%<(style|script)[^<>]*>.*?</\1>|</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>|<!--.*?-->%%g) {
  my $crawled_text = path("../crawled_text.txt");
  $crawled_text->spew_utf8($content)
}
```

I have made also some small style changes and `Path::Tiny` to save content to a file. You can use the default `open` and `print` (or `say`) if you prefer to do so. Using `shift` allows also to take the URL as an argument from the command line, which is more idiomatic than prompting the user for it.